# PHP If Else - Hide Button

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to figure something out!

I have the following code

```
if ($value = $rec['ip'] <= $cphigh_ip && $cplow_ip <= $value = $rec['ip']) {
     $cpyes="on ";
     $number= $value = $rec['ip'];
     $whmLink=$number[strlen($number)-1];
    }
    else {
     $cpno="not on cPanel";
    }
```

I also have a button below all this

```
<td><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.<?=$variable; ?>.test.com'" value="cPanel"></td>
```

I would like to add on the `else` where it will hide the button- any ideas?

Edit:

```
?>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Domain IP:</td>
        <td><?=$ipyes.$ipno.$cpyes.$cpno;?><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.<?=$variable; ?>.test.com'" value="cPanel"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mail Exchange:</td>
        <td><?=$yesMail.$yesHost.$noMail;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key DNS Records:</td>
        <td colspan='2'><?=$dnsString;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Why can't you just echo that button line out insdie your `else` block?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter You mean "comment" out?

Comment: You are assigning $value = $rec['ip'] three times. Functionally, you only need it inside the if statement. The two in the Boolean expression are redundant and just waste processing time.

Comment: Actually @Mike I have no idea ...  My read of this was that OP wants to hide this button when the `if` statement tested false. Do you understand this differently?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter echo the button line in my else block? Currently my else will display "not on cPanel (cPanelButton)" - I just want my button to be hidden or removed when the else clause kicks in. Not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could just move the button into your `if` block:

```
if ($value = $rec['ip'] <= $cphigh_ip && $cplow_ip <= $value = $rec['ip']) {
    $cpyes="on ";
    $number= $value = $rec['ip'];
    $whmLink=$number[strlen($number)-1];
    ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="cPanelButton" onClick="window.location.href='https://www.<?=$variable; ?>.test.com'" value="cPanel"></td>
    <?php
}
else {
    $cpno="not on cPanel";
    ?>
        <td></td>
    <?php
}
```

However you may prefer to do more separation of presentation and logic to prevent your code from getting too ugly.

Comment: @Havoux That's why I posted this answer as community wiki. It's almost like a simple typo type thing, so I don't care about the rep.

Comment: actually mike I ran into an issue. My button is appearing outside of my table instead of inside it. Any thoughts? So the true result would look like `"on (cPanelButton)"` but my button is just sitting above the table.

Comment: @Havoux Not without seeing your HTML.

Comment: I updated the question. Your solution put the button above the table. So I need to keep it in it's specific spot under `Domain IP:` Is there no way to disable the button within the else statement?

Comment: You have an error in your HTML. Your last row has 3 columns, but the other rows only have 2. Try getting rid of `colspan='2'` and see if that makes a difference. If not, it's something in your CSS.